# Are both 我家 and 我的 okay in 下班以后我去你家或者你来[我家/我的]，都可以?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-structure

In the this sentence,

> 下班以后我去你家或者你来我家，都可以。

Can I change it to;

> 下班以后我去你家或者你来**我的**，都可以。

Can I do this every time? If the context is clear then can I just say (sth.) 的？

Also does the second sentence sound natural (if it's grammatically correct)?

Comment: The 2nd one is understandable but a bit strange to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You‘re translating 'mine' as 我的, but this jars on Chinese ears.

It seems, Chinese doesn't have 'mine' as a possessive pronoun, as in 我的家 reduced to 我的， even though 我的 will get translated as 'mine' often.

All the shortcuts Chinese makes, but it doesn't like this anaphor!!

下班以后我去你家或者你来我的，都可以。
After class I can come to your house or you can come to mine, whatever.

我们/ 我的一个朋友
A friend of ours/mine

These sentences are acceptable to Chinese ears:

**那**不是**我的**，绝对不是！
**他的教育背景**跟**我**相似。

A very interesting question!

Comment: 他的教育背景跟我'的'相似 sounds more correct.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular sentence, it is much more natural to use the first expression. The second one is grammatically correct but I have not seen this usage among native Chinese speaker/writer. Though it is to common say something like `你吃你的我吃我的` [Eat your (food) and I eat mine] in other context.

Answer (score 1):

> 我去你家或者你来我的

The sentence is unnatural because 我去你家 doesn't have 的. It's natural to say 下班以后你回你的家，我回我的.

This sentence is a bit improvement from your second one.

> 下班以后我去你**的**家或者你来我的，都可以。

However, the 的 is omissible here. In speech, 我家, 你家, 他家 are common. People usually won't bother to say 你的家，我的家，他的家 because they sound wordy though they are grammatically correct.